Unity2D Trying to make a terrain generator with LineRenderer.But the line`s Length was wrong(maybe the pointPositon didnot calcaulate correctly?
Im a newCoder and im trying to make a rhythm Game.
I edit a timeline to Pop note while runtime.And i wish the ground could generate by timeline edititon too.
here i have a Terrain Class to keep the terrain information.Contains "time"&"angle".
    public int time;
    public string name;
    public float angle;
    public Terrain(int i, string j, float k)
    {
        time = i;
        name = j;
        angle = k;
    }

And then i use a Dictionary to keep the terrains in timeline.
public Dictionary<int, List<Terrain>> LineTerrainDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<Terrain>>();

private List<Terrain> Line_TerrainRangeList(int Time, string Name, float Angle)
    {
        List<Terrain> notesList = new List<Terrain>();
        notesList.Add(new Terrain(Time, Name, Angle));
        return notesList;
    }


At LineGenerator Script`s Start,I calculate the pointPosition and setPosition to generate the line with terrain.
    {
        point.Add(new Vector3(spawnTransform.position.x, 0, 0));
        for (int count = 1; count < NoteData.instance.LineTerrainDictionary.Count; count++)
        {

            int _initialKey;
            int _nextKey;

            float _tempTime;

            _initialKey = NoteData.instance.LineTerrainDictionary.ElementAt(count - 1).Key;
            _nextKey = NoteData.instance.LineTerrainDictionary.ElementAt(count).Key;

            _tempTime = (float)(_nextKey - _initialKey) / 1000f;


            float _distance = speed * _tempTime;
            float angleRed = Mathf.Deg2Rad * NoteData.instance.LineTerrainDictionary[_nextKey][0].angle;


            if (NoteData.instance.LineTerrainDictionary[_nextKey][0].angle == 0)
            {
                point.Add(point[count - 1] + new Vector3(_distance, 0, 0));
            }
            else if(NoteData.instance.LineTerrainDictionary[_nextKey][0].angle > 0)
            {
                point.Add(point[count - 1] + new Vector3(Mathf.Abs(_distance * Mathf.Cos(angleRed)),Mathf.Abs(_distance * Mathf.Sin(angleRed)),0));
            }
            else if (NoteData.instance.LineTerrainDictionary[_nextKey][0].angle < 0)
            {
                point.Add(point[count - 1] + new Vector3(Mathf.Abs(_distance * Mathf.Cos(angleRed)), _distance * Mathf.Sin(angleRed),0));
            }

        }


        lineRenderer.positionCount = point.Count;
        for (int j = 0; j < point.Count; j++)
        {
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(j, point[j]);
        }
    }

but the result is wrong, some line pieces`s length are too short or too long.
I cant find the reason,some big Bro please help me TvT !!!
i tried to generate terrain ground piece by piece but the connection has something wrong,so i try to make terrain using LineRenderer.
I would appreaciate all advice ,Thank you!
2024.5.9
I tried to debug and check the logic,find that In my LineGenerator Script s "if" part,the dictionary s Key should be "_initialKey", not "_nextKey".
The problem is solved,terrain generate correctly now!
Thank you JonasH !

I would suggest debugging the code. Unit tests might also help. I would also highly recommend making an Angle-type, since it is very easy to make mistakes with regards to degrees/radians.
